# How to highlight top item of ListView in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, listview

I'm trying to make a Listview whose top element should have a different UI then the rest. And the Listview is scrollable so the item which is visible and at the top of the list should be highlighted with different UI. Refer to[image] this image.

I want when I scroll through the list the top item at that instant should have a different UI ( the highlighted orange color).

How can I do this in flutter?

Comment: post code you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still an open [Github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19941) about this.

However, there are some packages [here](https://github.com/google/flutter.widgets/tree/master/packages) that can help you achieve this (Not sure about the performance with long lists).

Do check out the [scrollable_positioned_list](https://github.com/google/flutter.widgets/tree/master/packages/scrollable_positioned_list) from the above link. It provides a listener by which the visible items can be monitored as follows:

```
itemPositionsListener.positions.addListener((positions) => ...);
```

Comment: For code see this https://github.com/Nikhil-Wagh/ListviewWithOverview

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to checkout [visibility_detector](https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector) package. The [example for visibility_detector](https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector/example) (https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector/example) package does almost exactly what you want. The example displays the index of all the List Items currently visible on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

wrap element zero in a different coloured `Container();`

Comment: This wouldn't work because when I scroll the first element is not the top element.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what widgets you are using, but here is the general idea. There are two things you could do.

If you have a limited amount of list items, then you might want to use a `StatefulWidget` and have an `int` (or a `List<int>`) as a member to keep reference of the highlighted widget(s).

```
class SomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<int> elements;

  const SomeWidget({Key key, this.elements}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SomeWidgetState createState() => _SomeWidgetState();
}

class _SomeWidgetState extends State<SomeWidget> {
  List<int> highlightedIndices = List();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: widget.elements.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => FlatButton(
          color: highlightedIndices.contains(index) ? Colors.white : Colors.red,
          child: Text('$index'),
          onPressed: () => setState(() {
            if(highlightedIndices.contains(index))
              highlightedIndices.remove(index);

            else highlightedIndices.add(index);
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

If you have a lot of items in your `ListView` you'd be better off using a model class that extends `ChangeNotifier`, and then have a `ChangeNotifierProvider` wrap your `widget`. You need to add `provider` package in your `pubspec.yaml` file.

**pubspec.yaml**

```
provider: ^4.3.2+2
```

**ChangeNotifier**

```
class SomeModel with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isHighlighted = false;

  bool get isHighlighted => _isHighlighted;

  void highlight() {
    _isHighlighted = ! _isHighlighted;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**build method**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: widget.elements.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ChangeNotifierProvider<SomeModel>(
          create: (_) => SomeModel(),
          builder: (context, child) => Consumer<SomeModel>(
            builder: (context, value, child) => FlatButton(
              color: value.isHighlighted ? Colors.white : Colors.red,
              child: Text('$index'),
              onPressed: value.highlight
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: This would highlight the element on Press. I wanted to highlight the top element of the list automatically. Even if the list is scrolled up or down the top element should be the one highlighted. For eg: If I scroll by 1 item, the top element will be de - highlighted and the next in list will get highlighted.