# Optimize multiple http calls in each item in listview Flutter

Tags: performance, flutter, dart

I have have an infinite listview in flutter and each item on that list need to make http call to get some data from server. I want to optimize call when user scroll i want to prevent item from making http call.
Any idea to make that

Answer (score 0):

A great solution, used by most of mobile apps is to fetch your cells depending on the scroll. Initially, you can load for instance 20 cells and when the user reaches the end of the list, make another call in order to load 20 more cells.
You can handle the user's scroll like so:

```
var scrollController = ScrollController();
scrollController.addListener(scrollListener);

double maxScroll = listScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
double currentScroll = listScrollController.position.pixels;
if (maxScroll == currentScroll) {
   // fetch more cells
}
```

Comment: i already using that to fetch data but the problem is that  i want to make http call on each item to get  some other data

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you really want to do?

Comment: i have list of articles that contain each article will make call http to get promotion they want to get promotion only when list is not scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to optimize could be:

1. **ListView.builder()**: Use the builder to construct items lazily. This can be used to avoid having bulk http calls at the beginning (items are built as user scrolls).
2. **Cache**: Cache the http calls for the duration based on your needs.

Comment: thanx for your answer but already using builder and store data in database and  they want me to avoid calls when list in scroll and when user stop scrolling, item make  http call

Comment: @Lionel dali, tell me if I'm correct, by saying `when user stop scrolling, item make http call` you mean to say you want to make http calls for only those items that were scrolled and is visible at the moment in the list?

Comment: @Lioneldali, well in that case, this other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64782973/8257908) of mine could be what you want

Answer (score 0):

I found litle solution for my problem.
I used library visibility_detector (https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector)
In each item ,I wait for 2 second if the item still visible I make http call if not i do nothing